# Any advantages to expanded nested scope keys (vs path-like) in YAML i18n translation files in Rails 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

*Note: I'm not a RoR developer, so if there is anything inaccurate in the question please correct me.*

RoR has its own i18n library. This library (optionally) uses YAML format for the localization files. In these localization files, key-value pairs are used where the value is the translation provided, but these key-value pairs can be within a scope (namespace), here are exapmles:

One example from here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

```
pt:   
  foo:
    bar: baz
```

> ... the top level key is the locale. :foo is a namespace key and :bar
>   is the key for the translation “baz”.

And another exapmle from here - http://ruby-on-rails-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/11/i18n-in-rails3.html

```
en:
  contact:
    prices:
      show_price: "%{price_dollar}$"
      quote: "Coordinator: & quot;Crucifixion?& quot? & lt;br /& gt; Mr. Cheeky: & quot;Er, no, freedom actually.& quot;"

  attributes:
    created_at: "Created at"
    updated_at: "Updated at"

  helpers:
    submit:
      contact:
        create: "Order"
        update: "Modify"
    label:
      contact:
        name: "Your name"
        company_name: "Company name"
        phone: "Phone number"
        email: "E-mail"
        comment: "Comment"
```

Please check the pointers for better explanation.

An alternative style one can think of is to flatten the scope attributes: for example, in the last quote we can say:

```
helpers.label.contact.company_name: "Company name"
```

I believe that the nested style can be very confusing when editing large or deeply nested localization files. And indeed I found a couple of places where this issue is raised:

- [accessing I18n translations yamls](http://groups.google.com/group/rails-i18n/browse_thread/thread/2961090db35f28a1/67ff1ea4095e323b?lnk=gst&q=nested#67ff1ea4095e323b) - a thread complaining about this same issue on the rails-i18n group.

> The reason of doing it was complications I met with working on huge
>   piece of data in nested yml files. Having few thousands keys in few
>   translations files, was making me furious when I needed rename
>   translation keys, move them to another namespace etc. and had to
>   scroll a lot, looking and wondering what is namespace of the key.
>   Also, resolving merge conflicts, checking for missing translations in
>   other locale files are much easier, when you have and see full key.

- And here: https://github.com/henrik/vim-yaml-flattener someone has written a Vim plugin to flatten the file back and forth to overcome the issue.

My question is: what exactly are the advantages of having the nested style. Is there any issues with the flat style that made the developers go with the nested style despite the drawbacks?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the YAML flattener plugin for Vim.

The main reason for the nested format, to me, is that it's conventional, so any tools or services we may want to use are likely to use that format.

I suppose there is some risk of making typos as you start repeating yourself, and renaming things means renaming them in multiple places – but they're also harder to find to rename, and your editor likely has good tools to rename in batch.

I could come up with more reasons (shorter lines, smaller files, less noisy diffs) but I don't think they're very important.

It's a good question. I'm considering using the flat format most of the time and only converting if I need to use an external tool.

Comment: Since I got an upvote for this answer just now: these days, I don't flatten the file, but instead use https://github.com/henrik/vim-yaml-helper with Vim.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the main benefit of the layout of YAML files is that it's quite easy at a glance to see the relationships between the configuration data. I spent a few years working with Python, which defines scope with white space rather than extraneous characters like {}, etc, so the paradigm is comfortable for me.

Arguably, if you have large yaml files...thousands of keys...then it's probably time to start breaking up the files into smaller, more manageable files. When I am writing code in general and I get a file of ANY sort that is that large, I refactor mercilessly to organize things more intuitively.

Largely this is druthers, I suppose.

Comment: This answer is totally irrelevant. The question is not about white space delimited vs character delimited. The qestion is about using nested keys vs using flattened keys with path like separators for the key-value pairs. Both styles can be used with either whitespace delimited (YAML) or char delimited data (eg JSON). I have provided examples and pointers so that the reader can understand the issue of the question.

Comment: if you see no value in the answer that's your business but it's NOT totally irrelevant. your alternate style helpers.label.contact.company_name: "Company name"  is still scoped. the only difference between that is visual presentation. You provide thye term "flatten" to describe the alternate style but it's NOT flattened conceptually...just visually. But I'll let someone else step in and try to provide an answer more to your liking...sorry

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be harsh. Your answer discussed indentation vs char delimitation. What you're saying here is spot on - the structure is not conceptually flattened, just visually as a formatting style. And that exactly is what the question is about - why did the developers choose the problematic style (in some aspects) and whether there is benefit in the visually nested style.

Comment: Yeah, that's really what I meant. That the visually nested style makes it easier for me personally to find things. I completely understand that other people might not appreciate that layout. My comfort with Python, HAML and SASS makes the YAML approach preferable for me. I don't think there's any real functional benefit but I might be mistaken.

Comment: I edited the subject line - I hope it now grasps the subject of the question more accurately and removes confusion between visually and conceptually.